# How to use jQuery validation to set the search bar to accept only a specific input?

Tags: wp-query, jquery, search

I'm new to the wordpress world. As a starter theme I was suggested to use the basic one given by underscores.me. The search bar is fundamental for my site, so I would like to customize it in order to accept only a specific input from users.

In particular, the only accepted input have to be of the form `xay` where `x` and `y` are numbers between 1 and 999, and `a` has to be the letter a.

Examples of accepted input: 1a2, 222a999, 130a28.

I read articles [How do I add a simple jQuery script to WordPress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11159860/how-do-i-add-a-simple-jquery-script-to-wordpress)
 and [How to Properly Add jQuery Scripts to WordPress](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/) on how to properly add a jQuery script in wordpress, but it doesn't work.

This is what I did so far:

Since the theme doesn't have the `searchform.php` file, I'm using the default search bar. In the folder `wp-content\themes\mytheme\js` I created the file `searchbox.js` and in it I wrote the following code

```
jQuery(function(){
        $("#btn-search").click(function(){
        $(".error").hide();
        var hasError = false;
        var searchReg = /^[0-9]+$/;
        var searchVal = $("#search-text").val();
        if(searchVal == '') {
            $("#search-text").after('<span class="error">Please enter a search term.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if(!searchReg.test(searchVal)) {
            $("#search-text").after('<span class="error">Enter valid text.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        }
        if(hasError == true) {return false;}
    });
});
```

I found this code [here](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/using-jquery-to-validate-search-box-input/), it will first check that text has been entered and return an error message if the search box is empty. Then it checks that the entered text only contains numeric characters. If either of these validation checks return an error message, then the form submission is stopped with the “return false” command.

This is not exactly what I'd like to have for my search bar, I used it just to try how to add a jQuery script.

Then in the `functions.php` file I wrote, at the top, this code

```
function add_my_script() {
   wp_enqueue_script(
       'searchbox', // name your script so that you can attach other scripts and de-register, etc.
       get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/searchbox.js', // this is the location of your script file
       array('jquery') // this array lists the scripts upon which your script depends
   );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_my_script' );
```

Then I tried to do a search on my site, I wrote nothing in the search box and clicked the search button. No error message appeared, and all the posts on the site where shown. Moreover, I wrote in the search box a word (which would not be possibile to search for since the command `var searchReg = /^[0-9]+$/;` should only accept numeric input, but again no error messages and pages where shown.

What I did wrong?

**EDIT**

The problem was due to

- wrong search field and search button IDs in the jQuery script
- Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Solution

- substitute #btn-search with .search-submit, and #search-text with .search-field
- substitute $ with jQuery

Comment: I don't think you need to edit the form itself but add validation to the input.  You could use jQuery to validate this and display an error message if its not in the correct format.  You could also use regular expressions and PHP to validate it.

Comment: Thank you, could you link me some guides to do it?

Comment: @RiddleMeThis I've updated the question, I'm trying with jQuery but there is something wrong because it doesn't work. Could you help?

Comment: It isn't working isn't very helpful.  What isn't working?  Debug your code, put breakpoints in and see where its hitting.  Also, I think you need to setup your regExp like this - var searchReg = new RegExp('/^[0-9]+$/');

Comment: Thank you for reply. "Isn't working" means that I added code to change the behaviour of the search box, but it still behaves as before. I edited the var searchReg with your correction, but still the search box behaves as the default one. Maybe the file is not loaded on the site, how can I check if it is or not? Now I'm reading about how to debug on wordpress support, if you have suggestions let me know. Many thanks

Comment: I installed Query Monitor and set WP_DEBUG to true in the wp-config.php file.
In the section Scripts of the plugin there is searchbox (the file I created with the jQuery script), does this means that the file is loaded?

Comment: It doesn't sound like your script is being called.  I tested your code and everything seems to work except the regExp.  View the source and make sure your path is correct to /js/searchbox.js.  Then you can add some console.log('tests'); in different places to see if its hitting

Comment: Thank you very much for the support. The path of the jQuery script is `wp-content\themes\sitename\js\searchbox.js` and the function `add_my_script()` in the file `wp-content\themes\matesvolta\functions.php` contains `get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/searchbox.js',`

Comment: Looking for `searchbox` in the site source code I found these results https://i.imgur.com/E0O4Jdh.png and https://i.imgur.com/e9mgZRj.png

Comment: click on the link to your js file in the above screenshot to make sure it isnt giving you a 404.

Comment: When I click on the link, it opens a new tab with the code of the jQuert script

Comment: I'm trying to inspect the page (with chrome) and it shows this https://i.imgur.com/GqMF5dI.png and https://i.imgur.com/7ASZyA8.png. I substituted the `$` sign with `jQuery`, the error is vanished, but the search box still behaves as the default one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does the job (there is `p` instead of `a`)

```
jQuery(function(){
        jQuery(".search-submit").click(function(){
        jQuery(".error").hide();
        var hasError = false;
        var searchReg = /^[p0-9]+$/;
        var searchVal = jQuery(".search-field").val();
            var searchLen = searchVal.length;
            var num1 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
            var num0 = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9'];
        if(searchLen < 3) {
            jQuery(".search-field").after('<span class="error">Enter at least 3 characters.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if(searchLen > 7) {
                  jQuery(".search-field").after('<span class="error">Enter no more than 7 characters.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if(num1.indexOf(searchVal.charAt(0)) == -1) {
                  jQuery(".search-field").after('<span class="error">First character has to be a digit between 1 and 9.</span>');
            hasError = true;
            } else if(num0.indexOf(searchVal.charAt(searchLen-1)) == -1) {
                  jQuery(".search-field").after('<span class="error">Last character has to be a digit between 0 and 9.</span>');
            hasError = true;
            } else if(!searchVal.includes('p')) {
                  jQuery(".search-field").after('<span class="error">You have to enter the character "p".</span>');
            hasError = true;
            } else if((searchVal.match(/p/g) || []).length > 1) {
                  jQuery(".search-field").after('<span class="error">Enter only 1 character "p".</span>');
            hasError = true;
            } else if(!searchReg.test(searchVal)) {
            jQuery(".search-field").after('<span class="error">Enter only digits and one "p" character.</span>');
            hasError = true;
        } else if(searchVal.split('p')[0].length > 3 || searchVal.split('p')[1].length > 3) {
                  jQuery(".search-field").after('<span class="error">Exercise and page have to be numbers between 1 and 999.</span>');
            hasError = true;
            } else if(searchVal.charAt(searchVal.indexOf('p')+1) == '0') {
                  jQuery(".search-field").after('<span class="error">Page first digit cannot be 0.</span>');
            hasError = true;
            }
        if(hasError == true) {return false;}
    });
});
```